# Where to obtain royalty-free assets that can be used in Android/iPhone games?

Tags: assets

I would like to create some Android and iPhone games in my spare time, but I'm not an artist.  Where would you suggest I go to find royalty free graphics, music and sounds that can be used as part of a game?

Comment: Shouldn't the "buy" in the title be "get" instead?

Comment: You might have better luck on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am open to both creative commons and buying quite frankly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Turbo Squid](http://www.turbosquid.com/) is used a lot for 3d assets, gaming and otherwise. I've also read about [Magnatune](http://magnatune.com/) being used for a lot of indie games, including [Braid](http://braid-game.com/). I'm not sure about the best source for sound effects, but I did purchase a bundle from [Video Copilot](http://www.videocopilot.net/), which was decent, but by no means comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/) (CC licenses), and the old [Blender model repository.](http://e2-productions.com/repository/index.php) If you think about purchasing models check out [the3dstudio.com](http://www.the3dstudio.com/) as well, as you can often find the same models as on Turbosquid for much cheaper (they take smaller cut of the deal).

Answer (score 0):

There are a good set of resources covered all accross the web for free audio, textures and 3d models. You just have to google it tbh and you will find what you are looking for. I would recommend the [Xna free content](http://learningcsharp.co.uk/free-game-content/) of the [learn c#](http://learningcsharp.co.uk) website. There are lots of other websites on the internet with free audio, texture and 3d model site reviews and roundup although you should find all you need there. Happy coding :). Ooh and check here out aswell, i used them before to make a small 2d shooter game, the most useful webistes for audio and graphics are the first three, below that and then you get into some fishy copyright documents but happy hunting anyways. the website is called funsplosion, just google with free game content and you should find it.